# Headless Cypress in docker container resolution always 1280x1024

Tags: docker, cypress, resolution

When I run my tests in the official docker container (image `cypress/included:7.5.0`) the browser is always just 1280x1024.
When running the same config, same spec etc on host, I get desired 1920x1080.

My cypress.json:

```json
{
    "viewportHeight": 1080,
    "viewportWidth": 1920,
    "chromeWebSecurity": false,
    "baseUrl": "http://phoenix:4000",
    "watchForFileChanges": false,
    "requestTimeout": 40000,
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 40000,
    "pageLoadTimeout": 80000,
    "video": false,
    "env": {
        "codeCoverage": {
            "url": "http://phoenix:4000/__coverage__",
            "expectBackendCoverageOnly": false
        }
    }
```

In addition, I added some config like it you can find it explained here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api#See-all-Chrome-browser-switches

My plugin/index.js:

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
        if (browser.name === 'chrome' && browser.isHeadless) {
            launchOptions.args.push('--window-size=1920,1080');
            launchOptions.args.push('--force-device-scale-factor=1');
            launchOptions.args.push('--start-fullscreen');
        }
        return launchOptions;
    });

    require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);
    return config;
};
```

Why do I still get 1280x1024 resolution when running from within docker container (`./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --browser chrome`)?

Answer (score 2):

I got it, I need to start my own Xvfb server first:
`Xvfb -screen 0 1920x1080x24 :99 & export DISPLAY=:99 && ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --browser chrome && pkill Xvfb`
Source: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Xvfb